# Creating a row of divs that line up horizontally. Whats wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I new to web development and I have been practicing using jQuery lately by making quick little bits of code. This is suppose to be different colored elements that move like a slider when the button is pressed. I can't figure out why my elements aren't lining up in a horizontal row. They appear to be stacked vertically for some reason.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#button").click(function() {
    $(".slides").animate({
      'margin-left': '-=720px'
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 720px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slides {
  display: block;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.slide {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 720px;
  height: 400px;
}
.slide1 {
  background: red;
}
.slide2 {
  background: blue;
}
.slide3 {
  background: green;
}
.slide4 {
  background: purple;
}
.slide5 {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <main>
    <div id="container">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li class="slide slide1"></li>
        <li class="slide slide2"></li>
        <li class="slide slide3"></li>
        <li class="slide slide4"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <button id="button">move</button>
  </main>
</body>
```

```
</html>
```

Comment: [this](http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html) helped me...

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your `.slides` container needs to be wide enough to fit all of the floated elements horiztonally:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#button").click(function() {
    $(".slides").animate({
      'margin-left': '-=720px'
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 720px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slides {
  display: block;
  /* 720 * 5 Slides = 3600 */
  width: 3600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.slide {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 720px;
  height: 400px;
}
.slide1 {
  background: red;
}
.slide2 {
  background: blue;
}
.slide3 {
  background: green;
}
.slide4 {
  background: purple;
}
.slide5 {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <main>
    <div id="container">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li class="slide slide1"></li>
        <li class="slide slide2"></li>
        <li class="slide slide3"></li>
        <li class="slide slide4"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <button id="button">move</button>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your intended effect is, but changing the outer div's (container) width to 5x720=3600px (as well as the "slides" div width, as the other answers pointed out), you get to see all list items in one row, and each press of the move button shifts the row by 720px to the left as is your intention I presume.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#button").click(function() {
    $(".slides").animate({
      'margin-left': '-=720px'
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 3600px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slides {
  display: block;
  width: 3600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.slide {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 720px;
  height: 400px;
}
.slide1 {
  background: red;
}
.slide2 {
  background: blue;
}
.slide3 {
  background: green;
}
.slide4 {
  background: purple;
}
.slide5 {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <main>
    <div id="container">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li class="slide slide1"></li>
        <li class="slide slide2"></li>
        <li class="slide slide3"></li>
        <li class="slide slide4"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <button id="button">move</button>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

Add this to your style sheet.

```
li {
float: left;
}
```

Comment: This wont work because the parent container is not wide enough.